# AutoFilter based on cell color: 'Run-time error '1004':'

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter my column based on the cell color that I used while I applied conditional formatting. However, I cannot seem to get it to work. I currently have the following:

```
Private Sub Dups()
    ' Filter out the duplicate order numbers in each sheet
    Dim lsRow As Long

    lsRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(rowOffset:=1).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select
    ' Add the Duplicate Conditional formatting
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    ' Filter the sheet to only show conditional formatting
    ActiveSheet.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor


End Sub
```

When I step into the code, it breaks at:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:"=RGB(255, 199, 206)", Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```

I am getting the error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Did you try `ActiveSheet.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:"=RGB(255, 199, 206)", Operator:=xlFilterCellColor`?

Comment: Yea i tried that and it still comes back with the same error.

Comment: This doesn't really fix your issue, but the "Wrong number of arguments" error is being produced by the fact you aren't specifying a range: `ActiveSheet.Range.AutoFilter` should maybe be something like `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter`

Comment: updated the code to reflect @Tim suggestion. Got a new error which is updated up top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```